# how to set the Live Wallpaper as default wallpaper?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I created an live wallpaper application, like how we get default wallpaper on home screen, how to set the Live Wallpaper as default wallpaper even after my Android mobile is restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting live wallpapers are reserved for platform applications, e.g. the live wallpaper picker bundled with the device (the permission `android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT` is defined as `signatureOrSystem`).

You're not going to be able to do this without either rooting the device. What you can do is show the wallpaper chooser to the user using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag
startActivity(intent);
```

You can show a notification to a user when a new wallpaper is available (or upon system boot) and when the user clicks that notification launch the chooser using the above code so he can select your wallpaper.

Comment: do u have any idea about to set videourl as as stream...as WallpaperManager provide WallpaperManager.setStream(InputStream);
but it work for image only?

Comment: This might help you: https://ikaruga2.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/video-live-wallpaper-part-1/

Comment: i checked all three parts...there they are using old sdk...in new sdk android provide new featues to play video from java layer itself...here i am able to run local video as an live wallpaper but not able to do same for video url...any idea

Comment: I haven't looked into it yet. Will check it out and see if I find anything.

Comment: Sure. Post this specific topic as another question. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: anup do have any idea how to set live wallpaper from application

Comment: same answer as above. you can't do it. You can only show chooser and the user will have to select it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18858/discussion-between-shubh-and-anup-cowkur)